# Typescript type of concrete subclasses of an abstract class

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I'm trying to resolve this specific case in Typescript:

[Typescript Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20foo%20%7B%0D%0A%09abstract%20bar()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo1%20extends%20foo%20%7B%0D%0A%09bar()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09alert(1)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09y%3A%20number%20%3D%203%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo2%20extends%20foo%20%7B%0D%0A%09bar()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09alert(2)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20myFooClasses%3A%20Array%3Ctypeof%20foo%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0AmyFooClasses.push(Foo1)%3B%0D%0AmyFooClasses.push(Foo2)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AmyFooClasses.forEach((item)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09let%20a%20%3D%20new%20item()%3B%0D%0A%09a.bar()%3B%0D%0A%7D))

```
abstract class foo {
    abstract bar();
}

class Foo1 extends foo {
    bar() {
        alert(1);
    }

    y: number = 3;
}

class Foo2 extends foo {
    bar() {
        alert(2);
    }
}

let myFooClasses: Array<typeof foo> = [];
myFooClasses.push(Foo1);
myFooClasses.push(Foo2);

myFooClasses.forEach((item) => {
    let a = new item();
    a.bar();
})
```

Specifically, the problem is that `myFooClasses` could technically contain `foo` which is abstract and Typescript warns about this. But I really want to constrain the type of `myFooClasses` to concrete classes inheriting from `foo`. Is there any way of specifying this in Typescript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array type should be:

```
let myFooClasses: Array<{ new (): foo }> = [];
```

and then this:

```
myFooClasses.push(foo);
```

produces this error:

> Argument of type 'typeof foo' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   '{ new (): foo }'. Can not assign an abstract constructor type to a
>   non-abstract constructor type.

You can also do:

```
type FooConstructor = { new (): foo };
let myFooClasses: FooConstructor[] = [];
```